# Unable to send aws iot mqtt messages into aws kinesis firehose in a batch mode

Tags: aws-iot, amazon-kinesis-firehose

This is my mqtt payload

```
{   "type": "1",   "data": [
    {
      "customer_org_id": "777233",
      "vdms_id": "2",
      "vendor_id": "2",
      "remote_session_type": "open",
      "timestamp": "125434115",
      "email": "rajweeeeeath@acdercessonline.io",
      "network": "iptv"
    },
    {
      "customer_org_id": "555777233",
      "vdms_id": "5552",
      "vendor_id": "5552",
      "remote_session_type": "555open",
      "timestamp": "1255555434115",
      "email": "rajweeeeeat5555h@acdercessonline.io",
      "network": "iptv5555"
    }   ] }
```

Here is my iot Sql Rule

```
SELECT (select * from data) AS messages FROM 'test/fairfield' where type = '1'
```

I am trying to generate a json array so that I can ingest this into kinesis firehose in batchmode.
However, I am getting an error message

```
"errorMessage": "Failed to send message to Firehose. The error received was The payload must be a valid json array when batchMode=true, e.g. '[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]'. Message arrived on: test/fairfield
```

Note: I even tried SELECT data from 'test/fairfield' where type = '1'
But, i am getting the same error.
Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think following rule did the magic which is part of new sql version 2016-03-23

```
SELECT VALUE data FROM 'test' where type = '1'
```

However, I would still like to know, if we can pick specific elements of each object within an array and rename the keys.

Comment: like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/dynamic-partitioning.html ?